# Share WebAssembly.Memory between module instances

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I want to instantiate a WebAssembly module using the WebAssembly.Memory object created by a previous Module instance (all this using emscripten's glue code), is that feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit easier to create a memory object yourself and then inject it during instantiation of one or more WASM modules. I managed to do this with Emscripten by overriding [instantiateWasm](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html#Module.instantiateWasm).

Start by creating a memory that will be shared by the WASM instances:

```
var TOTAL_MEMORY = 16777216;
var WASM_PAGE_SIZE = 65536;
var wasmMemory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ 'initial': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE, 'maximum': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE });
var buffer = wasmMemory.buffer;
```

Then implement a custom instantiator that injects this memory into the import object:

```
function wasmInstantiator(wasmBinary) {
  return (info, receiveInstance) => {
    var importObject = Object.assign({}, info);
    importObject['env']['memory'] = wasmMemory;
    WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(wasmBinary, { credentials: 'same-origin' }), importObject)
    .then((output) => { receiveInstance(output['instance']); },
          (err) => { console.error('wasm streaming compile failed: ' + err);});
     return {};
  };
};
```

Now you can instantiate the two modules using the same memory. Here I recommend to use `Modularize` (see [documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-can-i-tell-when-the-page-is-fully-loaded-and-it-is-safe-to-call-compiled-functions) and [settings.js](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/settings.js#L819), which means adding `-s Modularize=1 -s EXPORT_NAME='MY_MODULE_NAME_1'` to `emcc` command-line. Emscripten will create a function called `MY_MODULE_NAME_1` that accepts a `Module` object where you can override certain elements such as the instantiator and the memory.

```
var createInstance1 = MY_MODULE_NAME_1( { instantiateWasm: wasmInstantiator('module1.wasm') , TOTAL_MEMORY, buffer } );
var createInstance2 = MY_MODULE_NAME_2( { instantiateWasm: wasmInstantiator('module2.wasm') , TOTAL_MEMORY, buffer } );
```

With these promise-like WASM instances, you can now interact with the two modules:

```
createInstance1.then( (instance1) => {
   createInstance2.then( (instance2) => {
       useWasm(instance1, instance2);
   });
});
```

But - there is a serious caveat here: if both modules try to allocate dynamic memory in the same memory, they override each-other's allocated buffers! So far I haven't found how to resolve this issue :-(.

See working example in [This repo](https://github.com/adilevin/wasm/tree/master/two-modules-shared-mem).

Comment: Wow thank you (I also tried to inject the memory object of the first instance into the second one but that didn't work..). Regarding the dynamic allocation issue, isn't possible to just disable memory growth?

Comment: Disabling memory growth only means that the ArrayBuffer won't be grown, but dynamic allocations using _malloc, in most cases do not grow the memory - but only find unused areas in it. So, malloc is still available even if we do not grow memory. I'm not sure what's an easy way to remove "malloc" support from emscripten wasm files... But I'm concerned that programs without dynamic allocations are quite limited - basic collections and strings from standard library use dynamic allocations often. Without them, C/C++ is much severely limited.

Comment: Ok, I see :/ then it's probably better linking my project into one wasm module I guess. Thank you for your help anyway :)